# Can't write files to a newly formatted drive

Tags: format

I cfdisked and formatted a secondary hard drive.  It is listed and mountable but I am unable to write files to it.  Can someone tell me if I missed a step?

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you mounted it as read-only (ro). Remount it from command line and it should be ok. If you don't know how do that, type in terminal:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

and post here the results

Comment: Disk /dev/sdb: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30401 cylinders, total 488397168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000b0912

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1              63   488397167   244198552+  83  Linux

Comment: so, sdb1 is your newly formatted partition, as I understand.

 _mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt_

and that should work

Comment: That command seems to make the drive unmount and disappear from my desktop. I reformatted the drive as NTFS and am able to write to it. Was hoping to format with ext3.